# Kafka Streams DSL Topologies naming benefits

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

1. Is there any benefit to name Kafka streams processors if there is no state store and only stateless operations is used? Looks like only benefit is nice "Topology#desribe()" output?
2. If I use stateful operations and state store is used, but every time I run application I change my application.id and delete old state store - is there any benefit I lose if my Kafka processors in streams are not named?

For me it feels like if I use naming in Kafka streams with java and I change application.id every time topology is changed, there is no benefit and naming just pollutes my code and makes it harder to read, instead I prefer to leave it clean. As I understand under the hood - naming is used to identify topology changes, so state store could be refreshed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, in this case, the benefit is improved describing and logs.
2. Again, you lose readability of logs. But you are right, if you change the `application.id` you will not suffer from the topology evolition problems that one encounters normally with unnamed topologies.

Generally, it is best practice to name processors, see https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-topology-naming.html . In your restricted case, the only benefit would be improved correlation between code and logs - which often makes sense because most applications are maintained for much longer than they are developed, so readability of logs trumps compactness of code. Obviously, up to you in the end.